# How to fix LinkedIn Linkedin Advertising API { "status": 500, "code": "GATEWAY_INTERNAL_ERROR", "message": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" }

Tags: python, linkedin-api, endpoint

```
def get_organizationalEntityShareStatistics(access_token):
    API_BASE_URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
         'LinkedIn-Version': '202306'
    }
    start_date = datetime.utcnow()
    end_date = start_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
    start_timestamp = int(start_date.timestamp())
    end_timestamp = int(end_date.timestamp())
    time_range_param = f"{start_timestamp}-{end_timestamp}"

    params = {
        'q': 'urn:li:organization:{x}',
        'timeIntervals.timeRange': time_range_param

    }

    response = requests.get(API_BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=params)
    access_control_info = response.json()
    return access_control_info
```

I am trying to use this method to use the endpoint organizationalEntityShareStatistics from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http. and getting response:

> {     "status": 500,     "code": "GATEWAY_INTERNAL_ERROR",     "message": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" }

I tried to use different parameters in the API schema and I tried to change the version of the headers. The access token works as I tried it with the https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me and it works.

Answer (score 0):

5XX errors mean something went wrong in the server itself that is not a know error or something that is explicitly handled - in other words you might have found a bug, e-mail them with the exact details of your http request

the wikipedia on http error codes is actually pretty good https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes